# What's the difference between JSP and WS (web service) in Java

Tags: web-services, jsp

I want to create a web chat and i'm looking for a lot of tutorials but i don't know if i should use **WS or JSP**, and i don't know the difference between both.

I'm sorry for my begginer question, and thanks for your help.